# How do I elevate privileges when running appcmd from a nant task?

Tags: scripting, iis-7.5, uac, appcmd

We are using a Windows 7 box as build server.

As part of our continuous integration process I would like to stop and start an IIS 7 website. I have tried doing this from the command line using appcmd:

> appcmd start site "my website"

However, this only works if I start the console window by choosing "Run as Administrator", so it won't work out-of-the-box from NAnt etc.

How do I script appcmd to be run with elevated privileges (or am I going about this in the wrong way)?

Thank you.

Comment: Simply using the task scheduler, if you wanted to do this based on an event that can be tracked, will allow you to execute a script with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 1):

This is **NOT** an advisable approach at all, due to security concerns...

But, if you grant read permissions to the service that is executing the `appcmd` to the file `applicationHost.config` file located in the `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config` directory, you you should be able to execute a `.bat` file with `appcmd` commands inside of it from CruiseControl (at least in my case).

I did this on a Windows Server 2008 Build Server.

Comment: Well, given "Build server" security concerns are minor. Sometimes you have to. I more wonder why a build server needs that - my build servers ONLY build, nothing else.

Comment: Are you kidding?  Build server security is incredibly important unless you like shipping bots.